# Using django form wizard with allauth

Tags: python, django, django-allauth, django-formtools

Currently my user sign up process is implemented with allauth. Does anyone have any experience of how to make this a multipage process e.g. with form wizard from formtools?

forms.py (stored at users/forms.py)

```
class UserCreationForm1(forms.UserCreationForm):

    error_message = forms.UserCreationForm.error_messages.update(
        {
            "duplicate_username": _(
                "This username has already been taken."
            )
        }
    )

    username = CharField(label='User Name',
                        widget=TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'User Name'})
    )

    class Meta(forms.UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'title', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'country', ]
        field_order = ['username', 'email', 'title', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'country', ]
        
    
    def clean_username(self):
        
        username = self.cleaned_data["username"]
        if self.instance.username == username:
            return username
        try:
            User._default_manager.get(username=username)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return username
        raise ValidationError(
            self.error_messages["duplicate_username"]
        )

class UserCreationForm2(forms.UserCreationForm):

    class Meta(forms.UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = User
        fields = ['occupation', 'password1', 'password2', 'terms']
        field_order = ['occupation', 'password1', 'password2', 'terms']
        

    def clean_terms(self):
        is_filled = self.cleaned_data['terms']
        if not is_filled:
            raise forms.ValidationError('This field is required')
        return is_filled
```

For the views.py i then have

```
SIGNUP_FORMS = [('0', UserCreationForm),
                ('1', UserCreationForm2)]

TEMPLATES = {'0': 'account/signup_1.html',
             '1': 'account/signup_2.html'}

class SignupWizard(SessionWizardView):
    def get_template_names(self):
        return [TEMPLATES[self.steps.current]]

    def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):

        for form in form_list:
            if isinstance(form, UserCreationForm):
                print('form1')
                user = form.save(self.request)

            elif isinstance(form, UserCreationForm2):
                userprofile = form.save(commit=False)
                user = self.request.user
                userprofile.user = user
                userprofile.save()
                print('form2')
        return HttpResponseRedirect(settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL)
```

What I find though is that after completing the first form and clicking to continue to the second the user is redirected to the inbuilt allauth login: at accounts/signup/

Does anyone have any advice?